# ggplot2: display text labels from one group only

Tags: r, ggplot2

**My setup:**

I have a tibble of basketball players and their statistics.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  season = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014,
             2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
  player = c("player_a", "player_a", "player_a", "player_a", "player_a",
             "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg"),
  fg_perc = c(.4912, .6083, .3095, .5525, .4289,
              .4825, .4836, .4819, .4860, .4848),
  points_game = c(20, 18, 15, 19, 18,
                  12, 12, 13, 11, 12)
)
```

I've displayed a certain column (fg_perc) as a geom_line() for both player_a and league_avg.  I've also wrapped it in a custom function, as I'll be using the same method for other statistics.

```
make_chart <- function(target_column) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes_string("season", target_column, label = target_column)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = player), size = 1.33)
}

make_chart("fg_perc")
```

**My issue:**

I want to display the fg_perc values as percentages  for player_a data only. I can't figure out how to do this without eliminating the legend (when I spread() league_avg).  I'm looking for a solution that will also be able to keep non-percentage numbers as-is, and display them in similar fashion (e.g. points_game for player_a only). The output would look something like this (please excuse the MS Paint):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Use `geom_text` to show the percentage, you restrict it only on player_A

Comment: It is great you included a reproducible example, for which I upvoted this question. However, you did make your example far too complex: the use of `tibble` requires people to download several packages while this can also be handled using `data.frame`, and the function that plots also does not add anything to the question, only makes it harder to read. Make it as easy as possible to answer the question, this increases the chance people volunteer some time to help you out.

Comment: I see what you're saying; will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your `make_chart` function without hardcoding, you'll want to use non-standard evaluation (nse).  Many of the `tidyverse` functions have nse versions, indicated by a `_` after the function name.  You would use these versions if you're using them programmatically.

Below would be a rough example of using the nse versions of `aes` and `filter`, `aes_` and `filter_`.  There is a lot more to building functions using nse than what I've done here.  I suggest you read the [dplyr vignette on nse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for more.

I simply replicated the solution @OmaymaS provided, with a `filter_` rather than the `ifelse`.  I also took the liberty of adding a data parameter `.data` to your function, along with a `player_highlight` parameter.  The `.data` lets your function be pipeable and the `player_highight` lets you choose which player you want to highlight (as they'll probably be more than one).  You'll most likely want to expand the functionality, and should do so!

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  season = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014,
             2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
  player = c("player_a", "player_a", "player_a", "player_a", "player_a",
             "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg", "league_avg"),
  fg_perc = c(.4912, .6083, .3095, .5525, .4289,
              .4825, .4836, .4819, .4860, .4848),
  points_game = c(20, 18, 15, 19, 18,
                  12, 12, 13, 11, 12)
)


make_chart <- function(.data, target_column, player_highlight) {
    ggplot(.data, aes_(x = ~season, y = as.name(target_column))) + 
    geom_line(aes_(color = ~player), size = 1.33) +
    geom_text(data = filter_(.data, ~ player == player_highlight), aes_(label = as.name(target_column)))
}

make_chart(df,"fg_perc","player_a")

df %>% 
  make_chart("fg_perc","player_a")
```

Comment: That did it (plus OmaymaS's workaround for the percent sign). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Check this out:
You can set your condition with ifelse inside geom_text:

- if player==the player of interest, the label will be the % value
- otherwise, the label will be empty " "

You can whatever condition you want, or multiple players.

```
df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(season,fg_perc))+
        geom_line(aes(color = player), size = 1.33)+
        geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(player=="player_a",paste0(100*fg_perc,"%")," ")))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to wrap the code in a function, you can use try the following, where you use **aes_string** inside **geom_text** to be able to pass the column name as a string.

**In case** all your target columns are percentages:

- you can multiply the column by 100 in advance inside the function *(or mutate before passing the df)*

  ```
  make_chart <- function(target_column) {

      df[,target_column] <- 100*df[,target_column]

      df %>% 
              ggplot(aes_string("season", target_column)) + 
              geom_line(aes(color = player), size = 1.33) +
              geom_text(data=filter(df,player=="player_a"),
                        aes_string(label=target_column))+
              # a work around to add the % sign
              geom_text(data=filter(df,player=="player_a"),
                        aes(label="%"),
                        hjust=-1.5) }
  ```

[image]

Comment: +1, but could you explain more why this actually works? This would make it more valueable to the OP and the rest of the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Added a simple explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the info; it's still not working inside of the custom make_chart() function, though.  I'm trying to pass the column name as an argument to avoid hardcoding it when I run for many other statistics.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up combining your percent workaround with Jake's non-standard evaluation answer to solve my problem

Comment: The best solution IMO => `ifelse(player=="player_a",paste0(100*fg_perc,"%")," ")` Killed it for me !! Two thumbs up. **My vote goes here** !!

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to use the `geom_label` geometry with a tweaked `label` aesthetic:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(season, fg_perc, color = player)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_label(aes(label = ifelse(player == 'league_avg', NA, fg_perc)))
```

So now only for the `label` we set the `fg_perc` values to `NA` if the `player` is `league_avg`, this omits them from the plot.

[image]

Comment: why not just pass `geom_label(data = filter(df, player == "player_a")` save a loop?

Comment: I like your solution, but it probably does not matter in time.

Comment: Thank you for the info; it's still not working inside of the custom `make_chart()` function, though.  I'm trying to pass the column name as an argument to avoid hardcoding it when I run for many other statistics.  I've gotten it to work without percent formatting with `aes_string()`, but not with percent formatting.