# In ggplot I would like to not label geom_col bars whose value is zero, just the one's that have a value (they are all positive)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-col

When labeling columns on a geom_col plot I can label them with this code:

```
geom_text(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, label = Cases), vjust = -0.5)+
```

some values are zero for Cases, and I would like not to show those.

Comment: Try `geom_text(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, label = ifelse(Cases !=0, Cases, "")), vjust = -0.5)`

Comment: ifelse, works, thank you very much, learning more every day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: display text labels from one group only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658754/ggplot2-display-text-labels-from-one-group-only)

Answer (score 2):

You could also filter the data within the call of `geom_label()`:

```
structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), n = c(3, 
5, 10, 7, 5, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = n, label = n))+
  geom_col(stat = "identity")+
  geom_label(data = df %>% dplyr::filter(n > 0), vjust = 0.5)
```

[image]